# addressing array elements in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm very new to assembly and NASM and there is a code:

```
    SECTION .data       
array db 89, 10, 67, 1, 4, 27, 12, 34, 86, 3
wordvar dw      123     

    SECTION .text       
        global main     
main:               

    mov eax, [wordvar]
    mov ebx, [array+1]
    mov ebx,0       
    mov eax,1       
    int 0x80
```

Then I run the executable through GDB eax register is set to value 123 as intended, but in ebx there is some mess instead of the array elements value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're loading 32-bit values from memory, you should declare `array` and `wordvar` using `dd` rather than `db`/`dw` so that each entry gets four bytes:

```
array   dd 89, 10, 67, 1, 4, 27, 12, 34, 86, 3
wordvar dd 123
```

Also, the indexing in the following is wrong:

```
mov ebx, [array+1]
```

You probably meant:

```
mov ebx, [array+1*4]
```

Comment: Alternative fixes: `movzx eax, word [wordvar]` and `movzx ebx, byte [array+1]`